# ASP.NET WebAPI - how to pass object with $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've a ASP.NET WebAPI control below :

```
public SomeObject GetBenchMarkData(Comment comment)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
```

On Client side I'm trying this below:

```
var comment = { ID: 0, Text: $('#text').val(), Author: $('#author').val(), Email: $('#email').val(), GravatarUrl: '' };
            var json = JSON.stringify(comment);
            $.getJSON("api/MintEIQAPI/" + json,
```

The problem is the GetBenchMarkData action never gets called with above getJSON query.

Could someone please help me, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `getJSON` executes a `GET` request to the server. For passing in entire objects, **you have to execute a `POST` request**.

In the **case of a GET**, the JavaScript object you pass to the jQuery Ajax calls will normally be transformed into URL encoded parameters which could then be taken individually by your server-side method like

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/someurl/getbenchmarkdata",
  data: JSON.stringify({ filterValue: "test" }),
  type: "GET"
  ...
```

});

and on your server-side

```
public SomeObject GetBenchMarkData(String filterValue)
{
   ...
}
```

Instead, **if you want to transmit a whole object**, you should execute the ajax call as a POST, like

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/someurl/benchmarkdata",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ title: "My title"}),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    ...
});
```

And your server-side method must take an object with a property `Title` of type `String`.

My [blog post might be of help here too](http://juristr.com/blog/2011/08/posting-json-data-to-aspnet-mvc-3-web/).

Comment: Thanks @Juri, did not work should i include HTTPPOST for Action?

Comment: @nilpun Updated my post and made it more clear (hopefully) :)

Answer (score 17):

By default, if you are passing a complex type through a GET, you need to decorate the action parameter with a FromUri attribute.

On the client:

```
$.get('api/movies/test',
      {Name:'Henrique', Age:'24'}, 
      function (res) {
           console.log(res);
      }
);
```

On the controller:

```
public void Get([FromUri] Customer c)
{
    ...
}
```

This way your are telling the WebApi to deserialize the parameter from the query string. Also, note that you don't stringfy the object passed to the server.

This blog post explains the differences of the WebApi and MVC model bindings:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx

Comment: Definitely the better way of going about this. Thanks for posting